# How to simulate a .NET HTTP response?

Tags: c#, .net, http, response, simulation

I’m developing a C# .NET Framework application which has to parse status protocols from different devices in the JSON format.
These protocols are obtained via http requests (System.Net.WebRequest and .Response). I don’t have the opportunity to receive these protocols directly from the devices, but I have a technical specification. So I need to simulate the response.
How can I test this: I need a URL where I can store my JSON data and from where I can receive and load this data into my applicaton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just read the JSONs from a file(s) to "simulate" a response. If you want to make HTTP-Requests then you have to use a mocked API. For this purpose you can try [Mocky](https://designer.mocky.io). Just click on `NEW MOCK` on the website and create your custom mocked API. You will get an URL that will response with the headers and data that you configured.

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for!